# Creating a cipher, and function pointer error appears EDITED! Cipher compiles but duplicates capitals

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am trying to solve the caesar problem in cs50 and when I try to compile the code, I keep getting the error "called object type 'char [4]' is not a function or function pointer". I thought this might be because I am using the %c placeholder in the code instead of %s for string, so I changed it, and it gives me the same message. I'm not quite sure where to go from here, because in theory, %c should work right? and if not, %c, than %s should, at least I think so. Is there some other insidious error hiding in my code that is tripping up the program even before the error message pops on line 32? I really thought I was doing so good this time. If I am making some super obvious mistake can you please point me in the right direction?

Thank you. Much appreciated!

Reags

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv [])
{

    // validating correct number of command line argument and type
    if (argc != 2 && isdigit (argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

   // converting valid string input to integer
   int key = atoi(argv[1]);

   // getting user input for text to encipher
   string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
   printf("ciphertext: ");

   // laying groundwork for 'for' loop
   int n = strlen(plaintext);

   // creating iteration loop for each letter in string
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
        // Rotating upper letters
        if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c," (((plaintext[i] - 65) + key) % 26) + 65);
        }

        // Rotating lower letters
        if (islower(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c," (((plaintext[i] - 97) + key) % 26) + 97);
        }

        // all other characters (unrotated)
        else
        {
            printf ("%c," plaintext[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT!!!
I am still unable to check whether or not argv [1] is a digit. And when I try to do anything using argv[1][i], it kicks it back and says undeclared use of i, and frankly I don't even know how to define it other then "ith" which is apparently unhelpful.

ADDITIONALLY code now compiles but prints the orginal capital letter next to the new encoded captial letter and I have no idea how to fix it.

If anyone can help with either I'd sure appreciate it. New code to follow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv [])
{
     // validating correct number of command line argument and type
     if (argc != 2)
     {
          printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
          return 1;
     }
     // converting valid string input to integer
     int key = atoi(argv[1]);
     string plaintext;

    // getting user input for text to encipher
    do
    {
          plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    }
    while(plaintext == NULL);

    int n = strlen(plaintext);

    // creating iteration loop for each letter in string
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         // Rotating upper letters
         if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
         {
              printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] - 65) + key) % 26) + 65);
         }

         if (islower(plaintext[i]))
         {
              printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] - 97) + key) % 26) + 97);
         }

         // all other characters (unrotated)
         else
         {
              printf ("%c", plaintext[i]);
         }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message

Comment: `printf("%c," (((plaintext[i] - 65) + key) % 26) + 65);` should be `printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] - 65) + key) % 26) + 65);`

Comment: The compiler regards `"%c,"` as a function or a function pointer. And I dont think you check parameters correctly by `argc != 2 && isdigit (argv[1])`. First, you should use  `||` not `&&`. Second, you should check the function of `isdigit`. Also, please check `plaintext` is `NULL` or not before you use `strlen`.

Comment: The error messages are really a bit misleading. The message about "called function" just means that the compiler sees opening parentheses after something that isn't an operator, in your case after `"%c,"`. The stylistic advice about placing punctuation before closing quotes doesn't apply here: Place the comma after the string: `"%c", ...`.

Comment: Another error you should get is about something not being an integer subscript. "Subscript" is compiler lingo for stuff in square brackets: What is a₁ in maths is `a[1]` in C. The error comes from `isdigit(argv[1])`. Now, 1 is obviously an int and there are no other subscripts. Except that there are: Often, `isdigit` is implemented as a macro, which looks up the desired information in an array. That macro has the square brackets the compiler complains about. Anyway, `argv[1]` is a `char *` which cs50 calls a `string`  -- another macro that hides information. `isdigit` requires a `char`.

Comment: Okay, I have made some adjustments. I have made so many adjustments, I feel like I'm starting to lose the thread of what I'm working on. Now my code compiles, BUT, it isn't checking to verify the user is only inputting a digit (can't seem to make that work at all) AND the code it spits out if off when it comes to capital letters. So ./caesar 2, if you type in "Hello #1!" will spit out "JHgnng #1! It is including the original capital letter next to the new coded letter. I will post edited code in original post.

Comment: Style change, please change your 65 and 97 to 'A' and 'a' - this is much clearer.  Also, the `string` type and how your `get_string` has to be allocating memory for you or this won't work.  I hate how that is hidden.  You need an `else if` for the second if check.  That is where the extra letter is coming from.  You fall into the last else every time.

Comment: "the string type and how your get_string has to be allocating memory for you or this won't work. I hate how that is hidden."   Are you saying to not use the get_string function? What do you mean it has to be allocating memory?